# index view is not binding to the controller in my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, html

I have following module which defines my angular app.

```
                        var ang = angular.module('mainapp', ['ngRoute']);


                    ang.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                        $routeProvider.

                               when("/home", {
                                   templateUrl: "homepage.html",
                                   controller: "homeController"
                               }).
                               when("/quiz", {
                                   templateUrl: "quizpage.html",
                                   controller: "quizController"
                               }).

                               when("/", {
                                   templateUrl: "index.html",
                                   controller: "indexController"
                               });
                               //otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
                    }]);



                    ang.controller('indexController', function ($scope) {
                        $scope.btn = "Welcome"
                        $scope.Login = function () {
                            alert("Thanks ");
                            $location.path("home");
                        };
                    });

                    ang.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
                        // initialize if you can
                        window.history.go(-1);
                        $scope.salutations = [{ name: "Mr", id: 1 }, { name: "Mrs", id: 2 }, { name: "Ms", id: 3 }, { name: "Jr", id: 4 }, { name: "Mister", id: 5 }, { name: "Dr", id: 6 }];

                        $scope.profile = {
                            name: "",
                            email: "",
                            contact: "",
                            division: "",
                            feedback: "",

                        };

                        $scope.submitInfo = function (profile) {
                            alert("Thanks " + profile.name + ". Lets get to the Quiz now.");
                             $location.path("quiz");
                        };
                    });

                    ang.controller('quizController', function ($scope) {
                        //initialize if you can
                        window.history.go(-1);
                        $scope.questions = [
                                       {
                                           "questionText": "Why is the sky blue?", "answers": [
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 1", "correct": true },
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 2", "correct": false },
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 3", "correct": false }
                                           ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "questionText": "Why is the meaning of life?", "answers": [
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 1", "correct": true },
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 2", "correct": false },
                                            { "answerText": "blah blah 3", "correct": false }
                                           ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "questionText": "How many pennies are in $10.00?", "answers": [
                                            { "answerText": "1,000.", "correct": true },
                                            { "answerText": "10,000.", "correct": false },
                                            { "answerText": "A lot", "correct": false }
                                           ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "questionText": "What is the default program?", "answers": [
                                            { "answerText": "Hello World.", "correct": true },
                                            { "answerText": "Hello Sunshine.", "correct": false },
                                            { "answerText": "Hello my ragtime gal.", "correct": false }
                                           ]
                                       }
                        ];

                        $scope.answers = {};
                        $scope.correctCount = 0;
                        $scope.showResult = function () {
                            $scope.correctCount = 0;
                            var qLength = $scope.questions.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < qLength; i++) {
                                var answers = $scope.questions[i].answers;
                                $scope.questions[i].userAnswerCorrect = false;
                                $scope.questions[i].userAnswer = $scope.answers[i];
                                for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
                                    answers[j].selected = "donno";
                                    if ($scope.questions[i].userAnswer === answers[j].answerText && answers[j].correct === true) {
                                        $scope.questions[i].userAnswerCorrect = true;
                                        answers[j].selected = "true";
                                        $scope.correctCount++;
                                    } else if ($scope.questions[i].userAnswer === answers[j].answerText && answers[j].correct === false) {
                                        answers[j].selected = "false";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //console.log($scope.answers);
                        };
                        $scope.submitQuiz = function (quiz) {
                            alert("Congrats.");
                             $location.path("index");
                        };
                    });
```

I want to land user on index page with welcome button and upon clicking i want to take user to the homepage and when user fills info on home page it should go to quiz page.

But the app doesn't bind the controller to index page at all.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html data-ng-app="mainapp">
    <head>
        <title>WinPrizes</title>
    </head>
    <body >

        <div data-ng-controller="indexController">
            <button ng-click="Login()">{{btn}}</button>
        </div>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/main.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When the index page is opened it shows button text as {{btn}}. These are not partial templates . I just want to switch to different html pages as part of the navigation user clicks on a button in each page.

Comment: Look at the browser console log for loading errors? Since the interpolations did not evaluate it seems the framework had error during loading.

Comment: it shows the Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=indexController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using ngRoute but you've not added the plugin library in index.html after the angulat.min.js In version 1.2 later angular-route.js has to be added separately it doesn't come inside main library. e.g.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.js">
</script>
```

Also, you're using $location service in all the controllers, so you've to pass that in controller function as a dependency.

You need ng-view directive on index.html to make routing work. And be careful that your views are partial views (containing partial html code). Also why you added `window.history.go(-1);` on initialisation of controller? Because it'll always go back to previous page onload o controller. You should add such code only inside some function which you're going to call on specific action/event.
Here's working plunker for your version of code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ADWf012Q7mTVBR3svPYb?p=preview

Comment: Now it gives me the error: Unhandled exception at line 8, column 7 in http://localhost:52366/Scripts/angular-route.min.js. even with url.

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'module' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @krrishna Check updated answer. Download the plunker & then check on localhost for url changes. Also if you don't want user to go view any url in your app if he's not logged in then you can create angular service which keeps track of login status & call it in resolve property of that route object.

Comment: unfortunately for me it doesn't go to welcome button( index1.html )page.It only goes to index.html. your plunker code works though. I copied the same to my VS solution .

Comment: Any error on console? you need to run it on localhost server for routing to work. use http-server npm module ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server ) or brackets editor's live reload.